# Problems in loading from NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsuserdefaults

I have a very strange problem while my app loads from NSUserDefaults. 
This is the code in my appDelegate:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *user = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[defaults objectForKey:@"_settingsUsername"]];
 NSString *password = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[defaults objectForKey:@"_settingsPassword"]];
 NSString *instance = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[defaults objectForKey:@"_settingsInstance"]];
```

The error is this: [NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'
It's very strange because i put in Settings.bundle -> Root.plist the default values for all the fields above.

Comment: @Stephen Darlington is right .But  for now paste your code when you pass or set  value in NSUserDefults.I hope than I can help you

Answer (score 1):

Oddly that's how it's supposed to work -- this confused me too initially.

I guess the thing to remember is that you can use `NSUserDefaults` *without* the Settings.bundle, so it can't be the only way to set default values.

Apple provide sample code, [AppPrefs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AppPrefs/Listings/AppDelegate_m.html), that shows how to copy the default value from the settings to `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Seems a good solution.. but... after I copied/pasted/changed it, the app won't finish launching after i click "Run". No errors, no crash. Just still loading something-I-don't-know...

Comment: I think the sample code from apple is a HUGE loop. Once i set the new UserDefaults with setupByPreference(), a notification is sent to the app delegate which calls setupByPreference() which set Userdefaults and so on... Thanks apple!

Comment: I think you copied it wrong. The `if (testValue == nil)` line is there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use that?

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standarduserDefaults];
NSString *user = [defaults objectForKey:@"_settingsUsername"];
NSString *password = [defaults objectForKey:@"_settingsPassword"];
NSString *instance = [defaults objectForKey:@"_settingsInstance"];
```

And make sure that there are objects for these keys.

hope it helps

Comment: I tried.. it doesn't work too, [defaults objectForKey:@"anyKey"] returns nil.

Comment: The code if effectively the same as that posted in the question -- it's certainly better but it doesn't address the question.

Comment: are you sure you are storing something in NSUserDefaults? Just like [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:anyObject forKey:@"anyKey"] where anyObject is anyObject and anyKey is _settingsUsername or _settingsPassword or whatever you will use later on.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that if the user hasn't gone into the settings for your app yet then all values returned from `NSUserDefaults` for those keys are nil. You need to handle that case and act accordingly - probably by going into the `Settings.bundle` and picking out the default value that you have put in there. I would just write a method that gets the value for a key and if `NSUserDefaults` returns `nil` it handles all the querying of the settings bundle for you.